# WordCount Project flaws

Tags: java

I'm working on a class project that counts the total number of words, lines, characters and paragraphs in a text file.  So far, it is working as far as the words go, but my character count seems to be off by 3 and the paragraph seems to be counting the two additional blank lines and I'm getting 5 instead of 4.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordStats {

    /* getWordCount() method will receive a String parameter
     * and return the total number of words by splitting 
     * the received string into words and increment word count */
    public static int getWordCount (String line){

        int wordCount = 0; 

        String str [] = line.split((" "));
        for (int i = 0; i <str.length; i ++){
            if(str[i].length() > 0 ){
                wordCount++;
            }
        }

        return wordCount;
    }

    /* getParsCount method receives a string parameter 
     * and returns the total number of paragraphs in 
     * the text file. */
    /*public static int getParsCount(String line){

        int parCount=0;
        boolean isText = false;

        if(!line.isEmpty()){
            isText=false;
            }

        else {
                isText=true;
                parCount++;

        }

        return parCount;
    }
    */

     public static int getParsCount(String line) {
         boolean isText=false;  
         if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                if (!isText) {
                    isText = true;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                isText = false;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

            int chars =0, words = 1, lines =0, pars=0;

            // creates new Scanner inFile
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("data.txt")); 

            //creates file to write updated data file.
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("dataCopy.txt"));

            //Loop that sends string variables to methods so long as there is another
            //line break in the file. 
            while(inFile.hasNextLine()){ 

                String line = inFile.nextLine();// read aline from the input file

                lines++;                        //increment line count
                chars += (line.length());       //increment char count
                words += getWordCount(line);    //Increment word count
                pars += getParsCount(line);     // increment paragraph count.
                outFile.println(line + "\n");
            }

            System.out.println("The number of Characters in the file are: " + chars);
            System.out.println("The number of Words in the file are: " + words);
            System.out.println("The number of Lines in the file are: " + lines);
            System.out.println("The number of Paragraphs in the file are: " + pars);
            inFile.close(); // closes file input. 
            outFile.close();// closes output file.
            System.out.print("File Written");
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.print("ERROR: CANNOT PROCESS FILE");
        }

    }

}
```

This is the input file:

```
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in
Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. 

Now   we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so
dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a
portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might
live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this. 

But,    in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground.
The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add
or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget
what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which
they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great
task remaining before us -- that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which
they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have
died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that government of
the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.



Abraham Lincoln
November 19, 1863
```

The output is this:

```
The number of Characters in the file are: 1495
The number of Words in the file are: 283
The number of Lines in the file are: 22
The number of Paragraphs in the file are: 5
```

Comment: "The output is this:" For what input?

Comment: Your logic for counting the number of paragraphs, or blocks of text, is flawed.  You probably have some extra newlines in the input, which is causing the extra paragraphs to "appear."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a change you can make to your code to allow it to correctly count the number of paragraphs, or continuous blocks of text, in the input file.  I create a `boolean` flag which is set to `true` if a current line has content, and is set to `false` in the case of an empty line.  Then multiple empty lines will only be counted once in the event that two paragraphs be separated by more than one empty line.  In addition, extra empty lines at the end of an input file will be ignored.

```
public class WordStats2 {

    boolean isText = false;

    public static int getParsCount(String line) {
        if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            if (!isText) {
                isText = true;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            isText = false;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Since you never showed us your input, we can only speculate about why the character count is also off.  One possibility is that the extra empty lines at the end of the file are again the culprit.  These "empty" lines are not empty, but actually contain one or more end of line characters (`\r\n` in Windows, `\n` in Linux).  So your program may be counting these characters.  Post your input and I can revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and replies.  I understand what you are saying, however, I think the input file, which I posted, is purposely mistyped to catch these errors.  Also, what am I missing that is keeping from printing to the new file?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but after looking at your input file, I can say my guess was correct.  You are counting empty lines and treating them as paragraphs.  This will only work if a) paragraphs are always separated by one and only one line, and b) your file has exactly one empty line after the last paragraph.

Comment: Since this is not the case, please try my code and let us know if it fixed your problem.  As for printing your output, let's get the input working first and then come back to that.

Comment: Meaning that the text file given to me has places were it is doubled spaced or not properly aligned.

Comment: I just checked your input file, and my logic should work fine.  Have you made any effort here?

Comment: The output that I am getting with your code is 17.  Changing the statement if(!line.isEmpty()) to if(line.isEmpty()) got it back to 5.  And my program is printing the file now.

Comment: I updated the code above.  I commented out the code that returned 5.  Yours is still producing 17.

Comment: Sorry...I had intended to use `line.trim().isEmpty()` ... please try again

Comment: hmm.  I'm not sure what is going on.  The line.trim suggestion is still returning 17. I'm trying a few things right now to see if it is in my main program.  The only difference that I've made was have the boolean variable inside the method as I don't want to use a global variable for that.

Comment: Wrong.  The `boolean` MUST be stored at the class instance level.  Your current code is always setting it to `false`.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for your help.  So would this same logic apply to the number of characters variable since that is currently producing 3 more than it should.  Also, The reason why I was not trying to use the boolean in global class level was because part of the requirement for this project is that you cant use any global variables.

Comment: How are you determining what the correct character count _should_ be?  In other words, how do you know that `1495` be incorrect?  Off the top of my head, I am assuming that you are not manually counting whitespace, and this is the problem.

Comment: Good question as I've been scratching my head about that one for a little while because when I try it with another paragraph of random text  and run the program I'm getting the exact number that Word is getting for characters with spaces. The paragraphs, lines, words are also correct and exactly like word, so perhaps it may have been a typo on project instructions. And no, I'm not counting individual spaces. lol

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain to me why my previous code was always setting the boolean variable when it was inside of the method?  I see why it works, but would like to understand the hows so I can explore other approaches for future use.  Thanks again for all your help and suggestions.

Comment: There is nothing much to explain.  If you make the `boolean` local to the method then it will always be set to `false` initially.